# toString method letter counter class

Tags: java, arrays, char

So I have this method to count the letters in a sentence and put them into an `int` array of size 26:

```
public void countLetters()
{
 String upper = sentence.toUpperCase();
 int ascii;
 for (int k = 0; k <upper.length(); k++)
 {
    char ch = upper.charAt(k);
    if (Character.isLetter(ch))
    {
      ascii = (int) ch;
      ascii -= 65;
      count[ascii] += 1;
    }    
 }
}
```

The count variable is my array and I have the ASCII values and stuff...
What I don't know how to write is the `toString` method
These are the Javadocs:

```
 /**
 *  Returns a String containing the letters in the sentence
 *  and how many times they occurred.
 *  @return returns a formatted string with only the letters
 *          that occurred in the string, each on a separate line.
 */

public String toString()
{
  StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer();
  for (Integer i : count)
  {
     a.append(i + " ");
  }
  return a.toString();
  //This is what I have so far, but I need to print them out in a format that looks like this: 
I sure hope this WORKS!!!

e's = 2
h's = 2
i's = 2
k's = 1
o's = 2
p's = 1
r's = 2
s's = 3
t's = 1
u's = 1
w's = 1
}
```

He doesn't want us printing out characters that don't appear in the string. The string in his driver program looks like "Aa678 ,.. zZ"; and in my tester it just prints out 0 0 0... 26 times whereas it should print out A's = 2 and Z's = 2.

the tester program looks like

```
public class LetterCounterDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "Aa678 ,.. zZ";
    LetterCounter lc = new LetterCounter(s);
    System.out.println(lc);

    if (lc.toString().equals("a's = 2\nz's = 2\n"))
        System.out.println("Works");
    else if (strip(lc.toString()).equals(strip("a's = 2\nz's = 2\n")))
        System.out.println("Close to working.  Check you spacing and capitalization!");
    else
        System.out.println("Needs some more work");
}

/**
 *  Removes:
 *      space -> 32
 *      (\t) tab -> 9
 *      (\n) line feed -> 10
 *      (\f) form feed -> 12
 *      (\r) return -> 13
 */
private static String strip(String s)
{
    String remove = " \t\n\f\r";
    String x = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++)
        if (remove.indexOf(s.charAt(k)) == -1)
            x += s.charAt(k);
    return x.toLowerCase();
}
}
```

The output says

```
A's = 2 Z's = 2 
Needs some more work
```

Whereas it should say

```
Works
```

UPDATE: Here is the full class. Note that I wrote all of this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class LetterCounter
{
private String sentence;
private int[] count;

/**
 *  Creates a LetterCounter object
 */
public LetterCounter(String s)
{
    count = new int[26];
sentence = s;
}

/**
 *  Sets all locations in the letter count array to zero
 *  @postcondition sets all locations in the letter count array to zero
 */
public void zeroArray()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < count.length; k++)
     count[k] = 0;
}

/**
 *  Computes the array containing a count for each letter 
 *  in the sentence
 *  @postcondition computes the counter array for letters a - z
 */
private void countLetters()
{
 String upper = sentence.toUpperCase();
 int ascii;
 for (int k = 0; k <upper.length(); k++)
 {
    char ch = upper.charAt(k);
    if (Character.isLetter(ch))
    {
      ascii = (int) ch;
      ascii -= 65;
      count[ascii] += 1;
    }    
 }
}

/**
 *  Returns a String containing the letters in the sentence
 *  and how many times they occurred.
 *  @return returns a formatted string with only the letters
 *          that occurred in the string, each on a separate line.
 */
public String toString()
{
  countLetters();
  StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) 
  {
     int c = count[i];
     if (c > 0) 
     {
        char letter = (char) (i + 'a');
        a.append(letter).append("'s = ").append(c).append("\n");
     }
}
return a.toString();
}
}
//The output is 
 //a's = 2
 //z's = 2

 //Needs more work
```

Comment: Here is some code: `for(int i=0;i<26;i++){ if(count[i]>0) a.append((char)(65+i) + " " + count[i]); }`

Comment: It still prints out `Needs more work` Any other advice? @Nayuki

Comment: How does the code print out `Needs more work`??

Comment: His tester program. Would you like to see it @Nayuki

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you.

String upper = "Aa678 ,.. zZ.qammar".toUpperCase();
//your method then following toString

```
public String toString(){
StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
{
   int v = count[i];
   if(v > 0){
      a.append( (char)(i + 65) + "'s = " + v + ", ");
    }
  }
 return a.toString();
}
```

Output:
A's = 4, M's = 2, Q's = 1, R's = 1, Z's = 2,

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here this should work for you:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        int c = count[i];
        if (c > 0) {
            char letter = (char) (i + 'a');
            a.append(letter).append("'s = ").append(c).append("\n");
        }
    }
    return a.toString();
}
```

Here are the things that had to change compared to your original code:

1. We need to iterate using the index because we need the index to get the letter
2. The current letter is the value of the index + the value of `a` since we want lower-case letters
3. The `'s =` part and a line break at the end were missing
4. A check whether the current count is larger than 0 was missing

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This still doesn't work... I'll provide my full class/tester in my question

Comment: When I print it out with a double `System.out.println(lc);` from the tester program, it prints out a's = 2 z's = 2 and then prints out a's = 4, z's = 4. My teacher told me to use some type of clear method I think the `zeroArray()` method, but I don't know where to put that statement

Comment: put this at the beginning of your `countLetters()` method `count = new int[26];`

Comment: Hey I actually got it to work, but thank you for the advice. I just had to clear the array using the `zeroArray()` method

Comment: Do you think you could help me with my other one, I asked it in another question

Comment: I can have a look later

Comment: Ok, that would be great!